# TryParse Date when not valid custom error message

Tags: vb.net, datetime, tryparse

I have a `TryParse.Date()` validation for validating the date passed in via textbox and if its not valid then show a custom Msg box warning.

However, while testing instead of returning a `False` and showing the message box it simply shows a error exception mentioning `String passed is not a valid Date`

Here is my code snipet

```
If Not Date.TryParse(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy")
    MsgBox("Please enter a valid Date", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Return
End If
```

So if I pass in a string value of `01/01/99d` it will show the exception message instead of returning and going inside the loop?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how [TryParse works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2). The second argument expect a date object. I would highly suggest you turn Option Strict On.

What you are looking for is [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2). It allows you to set your own format but you still need to pass a date object as parameter. Nice example on the page but I think you could set the parameters as Nothing.

```
Dim theDate As Date

If Not DateTime.TryParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", Nothing, Nothing, theDate) Then
...
```

**Note:** Based on Rango comment, even if you use "/" as a separator. It might cause problem with people that have difference culture. I would highly suggest you set the culture properly instead of using Nothing.

Comment: Using `dd/MM/yyyy"` with `Nothing` can lead to unexpected behavior because the slashes will be replaced with your current culture's date-separator which might be something different.

Comment: @Rango I did not know that, I tough ParseExact would force the /

Comment: No, because `/` is a [custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the--custom-format-specifier-1) itself. Use `InvariantCulture` or mask them with tick marks `'`. `Nothing`(or `null` in C#) means: _use the current culture_.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the definition for the overload of `Date.TryParse` that you are using, you will see that the second parameter should be a `Date` that is passed by reference:

[image: Date.TryParse Definition]

This means that the second parameter isn't expected to be a string.

You could change your code to correctly use the second parameter as so:

```
Dim dateParam As Date

If Not Date.TryParse(txtDate.Text, dateParam) Then
    MsgBox("Please enter a valid Date", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Return
End If
```